# get the maximum and minimum values of a sub group of columns in a dataframe in ddply in R

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to select the maximum and minimum values of a group of variables from within a data frame using the ddply function from the plyr package. However, it does not seem to work.

```
a1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
a3 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
f=letters[1:5]
d= data.frame(f,a1, a2, a3)

t=ddply(d,.(f), summarize,
    minima=apply(f[,c(1:3)], 1, min),
    maxima=apply(f[,c(1:3)], 1, min))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your expected output ? And is there a specific reason to use `plyr` ? I mean you can practically do everything in `dplyr` which is more easy to understand.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); d %>% gather(var, val, -f) %>% group_by(f) %>% summarise(a_max = max(val), a_min = min(val))`?

Comment: If you want to get the `min` and `max` per row, just do `do.call(pmin, d[-1])` and `do.call(pmax, d[-1])`  You may not need a group by

Comment: Thanks. I want to use the factor f to partition the df before calculating the max and min. That is why I use plyr (and because I am more used to that package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dplyr approach produces mins and maxes. You may need to reshape the resulting data frame, depending on what you are using it for.

```
library(dplyr)


# Create dataframe
a1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
a3 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
f=letters[1:5]
d= data.frame(f,a1, a2, a3)

# Get min and max value for a1,a2,a3
d %>% group_by(f) %>%  summarise_at(vars(a1,a2,a3),funs(min = min(.),max = max(.)) )
#> # A tibble: 5 Ã— 7
#>        f a1_min a2_min a3_min a1_max a2_max a3_max
#>   <fctr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      a      1      6     11      1      6     11
#> 2      b      2      7     12      2      7     12
#> 3      c      3      8     13      3      8     13
#> 4      d      4      9     14      4      9     14
#> 5      e      5     10     15      5     10     15
```

Comment: Thanks, I do not see the factor f used to index the partition of the df using the levels of it, like i did in my example.

Comment: Apologies, must not have fully understood the question. I've edited the answer to group by "f".